# How to combine two functions in Python

Tags: python, function

I want to combine any two functions, `funcA` and `funcB`, so they create one function that take the input of `funcB`, send the result to `funcA` and return that result

```
funcC(args) = funcA(funcB(args))
```

For example:

```
def sub(a, b):
    return a - b
def neg(a):
    return -a
```

For this example, my question is how to create a `negsub` function such that

```
negsub(3, 4) =  1   # neg(sub(3, 4)) =  1
negsub(2, 0) = -2   # neg(sub(2, 0)) = -2
```

and so on.

Comment: `def negsub(a,b): return neg(sub(a,b))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the most straightforward way:

```
def negsub(a, b):
    return neg(sub(a, b))
```

But if you want a function that builds functions out of other functions:

```
def combine(outer, inner):
    return lambda *args: outer(inner(*args))
```

Now you can do:

```
negsub = combine(neg, sub)
negsub(3, 4)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def sub(a, b):
    return a - b

def neg(a):
    return -a

def negsub(a, b):
   return neg(sub(a, b))
```